# Re-sizing and rotating is not working in fabricjs while using ctx.scale() method in canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to set canvas shape to oval using ctx.scale() method in canvas.clipTo function while doing this my re-size and dragging properties are not working properly in fabric.js.
anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue ?
here is my code
//html

```
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

//script

```
var w=canvas.width / 4;
var h=canvas.height / 2;
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {

 ctx.scale(2, 1);
 ctx.arc(w, h, 90, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);

};
 canvas.renderAll();
```

Here is my [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xadqg/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save and restore it as well in clipTo function -

```
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(2, 1);
ctx.arc(w, h, 90, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: how can i remove this clipping region from canvas do you have any idea ?